# Service Cases: Email Quick Action Button/Tab Not Showing Up

Tags: email, lightning-experience, service-cloud-console, email2case, quickaction

I have read a lot of documentation on this, and feel like there's something simple that I am missing that is not allowing the email quick action button/tab to show up on my service case feeds. My company mainly uses Classic mode, and I (as an administrator) am using Lightning mode, but even when I switch back to Classic mode, the email quick action doesn't show up there either.

What I've done:

1. Email-to-Case is enabled, and routing has been verified
2. Email Deliverability access is set to All email
3. Case object feed tracking is enabled
4. Object Manager > Page Layouts > Account Layout: "Email" quick action field has been added
5. Object Manager > Salesforce Cases > Salesforce Cases Page Layouts > Case Layout: "Email" quick action field has been added
6. Double-checked my System Administrator account has "Send Outbound Messages" enabled
7. My profile has Service Cloud Console checked
8. Tried creating a new custom layout
9. I have tested creating a case manually as well as emailing the routing address to create a case. Both work fine, but I can't respond to them.

Is there somewhere other than the Account Layout that I am supposed to add the quick action button? That is the only layout I'm finding.

Answer (score 0):

Email publisher action is not visible on Case after it is added to the page layout
Refer:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387865&type=1

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382424&type=1

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.